# Lubuntu 13.04 freezes when starting firefox

Tags: firefox, 13.04, lubuntu

after upgrading to Lubuntu 13.04 (fresh install from alternate) everything freezes when starting Firefox. 12.04 and 12.10 were fine and it's only Firefox causing a total freeze of the system.

Any idea?

could it be an nvidia issue?

Answer (score 1):

Installing `nvidia-current` instead of `nouveau` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
```

And then

> sudo apt-get install firefox

Comment: already tried that without success

Comment: Why don't you **add that and any other troubleshooting you have already done** to your question?

Comment: @lxdeuser what is installed on your PC?Drivers?anything?

Comment: it's a plain install on PC from 13.04 Alternate nothing special. The only bad thing is a Geforce 7025....